# ExtendedWebBrowser. Use 32-bit version of your browser

Tags: c#

I am hoping someone can have some input for this problem.
I did a ExtendedWebBrowser using the following article 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13598/Extended-NET-WebBrowser-Control
This is going to embedded inside a windows application where it navigates to a URL. 
This is the error I am getting when I navigate from the extendedWebBrowser. [image]

I can successfully to navigate from internet explorer. 
Any input on how to make the ExtendedWebBrowser use 32 bit version instead of 64

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the only solution is to build your application targeting 32 bit mode (x86 option). It will use the 32 bit WebBrowser.

Comment: How do I deal with 64 bit then? Can I have a different extendedwebbrowser based on 32 or 64 bit

Comment: I don't understand your question. If your app target x86 it will work with 32bit WebBrowser, else if it will use the 64bit WebBrowser.